# Scheme: lambda return #<void> instead nothing

Tags: list, scheme, lazy-evaluation, void, lazylist

i want to implement a lazy list that get 2 numbers as argument: low & int. The lambda will returns the lazy-list of all integers that are larger than low and divisible by int.

For example:

```
> (define lz1 (div-from 5 12))
> (take lz1 3)
'(12 24 36)
```

My try of implementation:

```
>(define gen_item
       (lambda (n int)
           (cons (cond ((= 0 (modulo n int)) n)) 
               (lambda () (gen_item (+  n 1) int)))))
```

When using this take implemenatation:

```
>(define take
 (lambda (lz-lst n)
 (if (= n 0)
 (list)
 (cons (car lz-lst)
 (take (tail lz-lst) (sub1 n))))))
```

When i run the lambda:

> (take (gen_item 5 12) 20)

The return value:

```
'(#<void>      #<void>      #<void>      #<void>      #<void>
  #<void>      #<void>      12      #<void>      #<void>
  #<void>      #<void>      #<void>      #<void>      #<void>
  #<void>      #<void>      #<void>      #<void>      24)
```

How can i prevent the lambda return `#<void>` and return nothing instead?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `cond` does not have a default case. So when `(modulo n int)` is not zero your get a undefined value. Add one like this:

```
(cond (predicat-expression consequent-expression)
      (predicat-expression2 consequent-expression2)
      (else alternative-expression))
```

Since you only have one consequent expression you could do this with `if`

```
(if predicate-expression
    consequent-expression
    alternative-expression)
```

Now if you don't any elements when predicate is not true then yuu should not cons anything when it's false but continue to the next true value:

```
(define gen_item 
  (lambda (n int)
    (if (= 0 (modulo n int))
        (cons n (lambda () (gen_item (+  n 1) int)))
        (gen_item (+  n 1) int))))
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I have still one question: why did you use empty lambda?

Comment: @PillPilon What empty lambda? I don't see an empty lambda.

Comment: @PillPilon I agree with Chris. I cannot se a lambda with empty body. A lambda  with no formals is there but it's also in your implementation as well (usually called a thunk)